# Populate CLPlacemark from SQLite data base

Tags: ios, objective-c

The instance variables on the `CLPlaceMark` class are readonly.

My app uses the normal procedures to populate a `CLPlacemark`.  The content of the `CLPlacemark` is added to a `SQLite` table of place marks.

Later on my app fetches one or more place marks from the `SQLite` table.  How do I use the results of the fetch to populate one or more `CLPlacemarks` since all the fields are read-only?

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize the placemark to an `NSData` object and save that in the database.

```
NSData* data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:placemark];
```

You could also archive an NSArray of `CLPlacemark` objects at once.

Then you can restore the placemark (or array of placemarks) from that NSData using `NSKeyedUnarchiver`:

```
CLPlacemark* placemark = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: I might be missing something but how can the data base be searched if the CLPlacemark are serialized?

Comment: @StephenJoy that's not possible unless you save additional unserialized data with each placemark.